# Azure - Is it possible to access a user's subscriptions/resources with only a log-in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I'm currently trying to learn about using Azure and its APIs.

I figured I could try to write a web-app (currently it's an Asp.Net MVC with .Net Framework in C#) that logs in a user and then reads his account info as well as setting up alerts with the Azure Monitoring REST API.

So far I have been following the guide that Microsoft offers when Registering an app on apps.dev.microsoft.com . All that has given me is an id-token (which isn't the one I need as far as I can tell) which lets me look at my Tenant-ID and a bunch of useless claims.

I've been googling a lot and I found some sample applications on github that access various things through Azure APIs but I haven't actually found one that doesn't require manually creating Keys or typing in the Subscription ID ...

Is there even a way to gain access to things like the subscription ID, resources, metrics, etc of a user that logs into their Microsoft Account through my app, without them having to manually set up Registered Apps, Keys, etc? Guessing OpenID and the id-token it gives aren't really all that helpful for that?

Any resource that points me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements here? What do you mean when you say "Without them having to manually set up registed apps, keys, etc?". Are you asking for a way to gain access to ARM APIs without creation an application at all? Or without having each end user create an application? The solution here should be that you create a multi-tenant application which allows many users to sign in, and you would gain access to the ARM API through their consent. This may or may not require you to set up application keys depending on if you are creating a confidential client or public client.

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to get people to do as little as possible in terms of setting up. Anything they *have* to do they do but everything I can read from the API I want to be reading. The best case scenario would if they logged into the app, saw their subscriptions/etc and then could choose which of their projects they want to set alerts for. Fully-automated monitoring and all of your info in one place.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how you can authenticate to Azure AD, so you need to choose which fits you best.

These are the five primary application scenarios supported by Azure AD:

- Web Browser to Web Application: A user needs to sign in to a web application that is secured by Azure AD.
- Single Page Application (SPA): A user needs to sign in to a single page application that is secured by Azure AD.
- Native Application to Web API: A native application that runs on a phone, tablet, or PC needs to authenticate a user to get resources from a web API that is secured by Azure AD.
- Web Application to Web API: A web application needs to get resources from a web API secured by Azure AD.
- Daemon or Server Application to Web API: A daemon application or a server application with no web user interface needs to get resources from a web API secured by Azure AD.

More details about each of them - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Also keep in mind that each Azure AD can have different requirements and setup. For example users may be forced to use MFA(multifactor auth), or organization could be using SSO with ADFS, so you need to have integration with that. Usually I think some standard Microsoft's "login" library is used, so when its time to authenticate - almost same prompt comes up from different apps.